# Selenium Webdriver, can not select element

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have an html like this

```
<td class="select", dataId="12o312p3o">   <span>
     <a>something</a>   </span> </td>
```

and lots of same td-s, just dataID is different. I want to select the td by dataID, but cannot find a way to do it. 
I am using selenium webdriver. Is this possible, and if it is - how could i do it?

Comment: There is problem in Your Html itself.
`<td class="select" data-Id="12o312p3o">
<span><a>something</a>
</span>
</td>`

Comment: the HTML is correct, may be I've entered it wrong. The question is, can i select the td by dataID or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If solution provided above are not working you could write some custom
>   websdriver + Java code like:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='select']"));
String s = e.getAttribute("dataId");
if(s.equals("12o312p3o"){
//do something
} else {
//do something different
}
```

Comment: Thank you all. The problem was in one iframe, that i didn't see :) My fault. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

To Find Element that has `data-id` with value `12o312p3o`:-

By Css Selector-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[data-id=12o312p3o]"));
```

By X-Path-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-id='120312p30']"));
```

---

To Find Element that has `data-id` with value `12o312p3o` and `class` as `select` :-

By Css Selector-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.select[data-id=12o312p3o]"));
```

By X-Path-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-id='120312p30' and @class='select']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Use xpath as follows:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-Id='12o312p3o']"));
```